# Get a substring after a certain word

Tags: bash, shell, parsing

The string looks as follows:

```
Event Id: 971
Time    : Fri Mar 28 03:50:03 2014
Type    : INFO
User    : ehwe
Message :
        Oracle_Connector_1,0: Number of rows fetched on the current node: 0.
```

I need to get the sub string that follows the **Message :**. So I in this case I need this
**Oracle_Connector_1,0: Number of rows fetched on the current node: 0.**

I've tried using  `b=${a%'Message :'*}` format but that didn't help.

Little help, please?

**Update:**

Some log entries might look like the next one:

```
Event Id: 970
Time    : Fri Mar 28 03:50:03 2014
Type    : FATAL
User    : ehwe
Message :
    Oracle_Connector_1,0: [IIS-CONN-ORA-001003] The OCI function OCIStmtExecute returned status -1. Error code: 6,550, Error message: ORA-06550: line 2, column 14:
    PLS-00201: identifier 'IT' must be declared
    ORA-06550: line 2, column 14:
    PL/SQL: Item ignored
    ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
    PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
    ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    ORA-06550: line 8, column 26:
    PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
    ORA-06550: line 8, column 7:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored. (CC_OraStatement::executePlSql, file CC_OraStatement.cpp, line 2,746)
```

Comment: Is what you want always one line after `Message:`?

Comment: Is this a multiline string? Is the substring in question really on a separate line or on the same line as "Message"?

Comment: It can take more than one line. Adrian, I've double checked on the new lines and it turns out that when this log entry is saved into a variable it is all displayed in one line.

Comment: @Dennis Is `Message:` is your last tag or after that another also there like `something:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
awk 'f; /Message/ {f=1}' file
```

- If the flag `f` is set, condition is true so `awk` prints the line.
- Whenever the text `Message` appears, the flag `f` is set to 1.

---

#### Update

If you want to print exactly the line after `Message` occurs, you can do:

```
$ awk 'f {print; exit} /Message/ {f=1}' file
    Oracle_Connector_1,0: [IIS-CONN-ORA-001003] The OCI function OCIStmtExecute returned status -1. Error code: 6,550, Error message: ORA-06550: line 2, column 14:
```

It is the same as above, just that after printing for the first time, it stops reading the file and `exits`.

To use a variable as input instead of a file, use:

```
awk 'f {print; exit} /Message/ {f=1}' <<< "$var"
```

See an example:

```
$ echo "$var"
hello
how are you

$ awk '1' <<< "$var"
hello
how are you
```

Comment: This will print *all* lines after matching /Message/.  Do we know the example contains the *entire* string, or is it only a snippet?

Comment: It is a entire string. However, there may be many more lines after the Message : flag

Comment: BTW, I get a single log entry as a variable and it's a bit tricky to feed it to awk

Comment: @Dennis consider updating your question with more possible cases. My answer is solving your current problem, you'd better indicate what edge cases we can be facing so I can improve it.

Comment: @Dennis nice! For your given new input, what should be printed? Just `Oracle_Connector_1,0: [IIS-CONN-ORA-001003] The OCI function OCIStmtExecute returned status -1. Error code: 6,550, Error message: ORA-06550: line 2, column 14:` or even more?

Comment: I just gave it a second thought and decided that getting the line that follows the "Message :" line would be absolutely sufficient. SO yes, just what you mentioned :)

Comment: @Dennis ok! I just updated with a one-liner that exits after printing the result. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry to nag you with such a stupid question, but how do I pass a variable to awk instead of a file name?

Comment: No problem @Dennis , see my update. It is a matter of using `<<< "$var"`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much fedorqui. Have an awesome day!!

Answer (score 1):

`grep -A1 Message | tail -1` should do the trick. -A1 tells grep the write one more line to the output (after 1) when a match is found.

Answer (score 1):

I expect `${a%'Message :'*}` to return the *first* four lines.  If `$a` contains the entire message above, reverse the match:

```
a="Event Id: 971
Time    : Fri Mar 28 03:50:03 2014
Type    : INFO
User    : ehwe
Message :
        Oracle_Connector_1,0: Number of rows fetched on the current node: 0."

echo "${a#*Message :[$IFS]}"
```

Outputs:

```
        Oracle_Connector_1,0: Number of rows fetched on the current node: 0.
```

Note:
Using `[$IFS]` because I'm too lazy to figure out an explicit match with the newline character.  That can be improved.

Tested in `bash` and `ksh93`

Comment: That's funny. When I define the a variable as an output from a server your method doesn't work. However, when I define the a variable explicitly as a text you method does work :)

Comment: Do an `echo "$a" | od`. There may be an extra space after the colon. Or some other difference.  Capture the exact data for your tests and experiments.